# Create a .bat file to open/click an application/link on the webpage?

Tags: batch-file, automation

I have a website that I have to visit daily and select an application on that webpage. I have creates the .bat file to open the webpage at start up however how can I take it one step further and automatically start the application on the webpage?

I have the following in the /bat file that currently opens the webpage.

```
@echo off
start iexplore myapps.logisticshealth.com/RDWeb/Pages/en-US/Default.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fRDWeb%2fPages%2f
Start C:\"Program Files (x86)"\Mitel\"Unified Communicator Advanced 7.3"\UCA
```

Once the webpage is opened I have to open one of the App pictured below:
[image]

How can I create a .bat file that will open/click on the one of the applications on the webpage, pictured in the screenshot? Is there another solution other than a .bat file?

Comment: I suggest you may try using a simple software to record the mouse and keyboard action and then put it as start up (see whether it suits your needs) .

One of the softwares are Mini Mouse Macro which is free. You may visit this link for this software and other alternatives

https://www.prohavit.com/blog/8-free-macro-recorder-automate-traditional-mouse-keyboard/#:~:text=Macro%20Toolworks%20provides%20free%2C%20standard,keyboard%20inputs%20and%20mouse%20commands.

Comment: Batch scripts are not made to interact with GUI applications, they are originated in text-based operating systems (like MS-DOS). Anyway, this question is off-topic anyway, because this site is not a free code/script writing service! So please take the [tour], visit the [help] and learn [ask] here!

Answer (score 1):

Kaia first you can't make the command prompt click links or open website links the real way to solve this problem is to grab the link that is in the website in our case a question link, and then do the start command `start https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65282527/create-a-bat-file-to-open-click-an-application-link-on-the-webpage` then your all done.